# in NTRU, can g be recovered given f and h?

Tags: public-key, lattice-crypto, key-generation, ntru, key-recovery

The NTRU key generation involves polynomials and their arithmetic in polynomial rings, which is a bit different from arithmetic in modular integers.
In the NTRU cryptosystem, the public key $h$ is computed as:

$h=g⋅F_q \bmod  q \tag{1}\label{r1}$

where $g$ is a chosen polynomial, $F_q$​ is the modular inverse of $f$ modulo $q$ in the ring of polynomials, and $q$ is a modulus, i.e.:

$f^{-1} = F_q \bmod q \tag{2}\label{r2}$

So, $F_q​$ is not simply the multiplicative inverse of $f$ in modular arithmetic but the modular inverse in the ring of polynomials modulo $q$. So, while

$F_q ⋅ f \equiv 1 \bmod  q \tag{3}$

in the polynomial ring, deriving $F_q$​ from $f$ is not straightforward and involves polynomial arithmetic, not integer arithmetic. At least with [NTRUEncrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt) it works so that the $F_q$ factor in $h$ cancels out with $f$.

Regarding my question about deriving $g$ from $h$ and $f$, from (\ref{r1}) follows:

$g \equiv h ⋅ F_q^{−1} \bmod  q \tag{4}$

And with (\ref{r2}), in theory, we could compute $g$ as

$g \equiv h ⋅ f \bmod  q \tag{5}\label{r5}$

My initial question now boils down to the clarification if this $g$ (\ref{r5}) can actually be expected to be *identical* to the $g$ (\ref{r1}) initially used in the key-pair generation - or could it also be "somehow equivalent" or even "one of many solutions"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, equation (5) in your question determines $g$ uniquely up to the possible addition of a multiple of $q$. But $g$ also has the property of having small coefficients (much smaller than $q/2$ in absolute value; depending on the version of NTRU you're looking at, possibly at most $1$ in absolute value). Both conditions together uniquely determine $g$: each coefficient is going to be equal to the unique integer of absolute value $<q/2$ congruent mod $q$ to the corresponding coefficient of $h\cdot f$.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! :) so it depends on version/implementation of NTRU, but most likely yes.

Comment: To clarify further: the size of the coefficients of $g$ depends on the specific version of NTRU, but the fact that they are small compared to $q/2$ is always satisfied, so the answer is always yes.

Comment: alright, I see, thank you! can you recommend any repo/lib/modules with which I can play around i.e. which do output g, f and h and allow me to compute f\*h? I already searched my way through github and googled, found some e.g. python code, but couldn't spot something that supports all of this (especially f\*h).

Comment: I would recommend working in SageMath. You can easily find NTRU code for it, and it natively supports the required algebraic structures, so multiplication should be directly available.

Comment: thanks for your hint to SageMath. I'll try it. in the meanwhile, I could test the Wikipedia example with Wolfram Mathematia:
```
f = -1 + x + x^2 - x^4 + x^6 +x^9 - x^10;
g = -1 + x^2 +x^3 + x^5 -x^8 - x^10;
h = 8 - 7x - 10x^2 - 12x^3 + 12x^4 - 8x^5 + 15x^6 - 13x^7 + 12x^8 - 13x^9 + 16x^10;
fh = Expand[f*h];
fhModN = PolynomialMod[fh, {x^11-1}];
fhMod4 = PolynomialMod[fhModN, 4];
fhMod4CL = CoefficientList[fhMod4, x];
g2CL = Reverse[If[# != 0, # - 2, #] & /@ fhMod4CL];
g2 = Expand[FromDigits[g2CL, x]];
Print[Equivalent[ g2, g]];
```
-> True
NumPy worked, too, btw.